# Securing Password used by TSQLConnection.Params

Tags: delphi, dbexpress

Using Delphi 2009, when using the TSQLConnection object to setup a dbExpress connection to a MS SQL server, if the connection is not using windows authentication, is there a way to setup the connection parameters so that the password passed to the object is secure?

At the moment I am doing something similar to:

```
SqlConn.Params.Values['HostName'] := 'dbserver';
SqlConn.Params.Values['Database'] := 'xdata';
SqlConn.Params.Values['User_Name'] := 'user';
SqlConn.Params.Values['Password'] := 'mysql';
```

If you do this and during runtime you take a memory dump of the application and pull the strings from that dump, you can clearly see the password.

Is there anyway around this, apart from using windows auth for the connection?

Comment: What about `TSQConnection.LoginPrompt` ?

Comment: You could store the pwd in your app in encoded form and decode it at run-time as you make the connection, but that won't stop it being visible to a packet-sniffer in transit to the server.

Comment: @MartynA: or in a memory dump that includes the `TSQLConnection.Params` data, since params are stored unencrypted.

Comment: See [Controlling Server Login](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Controlling_Server_Login) for ideas of how to handle DB passwords securely.  In particular, you can use the `TSQLConnection.OnLogin` event to provide the username and password on-demand when needed. Then you can store them securely wherever you want and decrypt them only when they are needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, oh, thats interesting!  I shall have a look to see if that helps.  Thanks.

Comment: @RemyLebea, ok so I tried to use this, but it still looks like the parameters string lists that are created internally by the dbExpress units are holding the password in memory.  Without going in and hacking the source for SqlExpr, Im not sure I can resolve this.

Comment: Once a connection has been established, can you then set the parameters to an empty string?  Using Remy's OnLogin suggestion, the connection can be re-established at a later time if necessary, then the parameter cleared again.

Comment: @MichaelVincent, yeah that doesn't work because of the way the Delphi objects have been done.  It looks like when the parameters are loaded in, they get passed around some internal objects, and because of the type casting that goes on, new strings get created all over the place, and the memory locations for those strings aren't locatable so you can't explicitly zero/nullify them.  I guess we are going to have to just hope that no one scraps the memory of the app/machine.